# Problems with assigning dimensions through python script

Tags: python

I don't know how to put this, as a bug or error in code. Anyway here is my code,

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(vertices=5, radius=1, location=(0, 0, 0))
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")
bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(MESH_OT_extrude_region={"mirror":False},     
TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 30)})
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
bpy.context.object.dimensions[0] = 0.7  // Does not work
bpy.context.object.dimensions[1] = 0.7
```

The code as you can see creates a mesh circle and extrudes its vertices and then set its dimensions for X and Y axis as 0.7. Well the code executes fine, but the dimension for X does not change. It remains at some 1.902.. . I need help in rectifying this problem.

**Note: I am using Blender 2.75.**

Comment: Do you see any unwanted messages in the Console Window? convertViewVec: called in an invalid context

Comment: No unwanted messages. I don't think print statements are needed, as the values are reflected in  Number panel( " N ").But, as far as I can see the value for dimensions[0] i.e X remains 1.902. In other words, the statement "bpy.context.dimension[0] = 0.7" has no effect on my object. But the next statement "bpy.context.dimension[1] = 0.7" works i.e the value of X dimension refuses to change using python script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The core of this question is

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(vertices=5, radius=1, location=(0, 0, 0))

# this doesn't produce expected results
bpy.context.object.dimensions[0] = 0.7
bpy.context.object.dimensions[1] = 0.7
```

versus

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(vertices=5, radius=1, location=(0, 0, 0))
# this does
dims = bpy.context.object.dimensions
bpy.context.object.dimensions = 0.7, 0.7, dims[2]
```

---

Plugged into your sample code:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_circle_add(vertices=5, radius=1, location=(0, 0, 0))
obj = bpy.context.object  # might need it later

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")
bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(MESH_OT_extrude_region={"mirror":False},     
TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 30)})
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

current_x, current_y, current_z =  obj.dimensions
obj.dimensions = [0.7, 0.7, current_z]
```

[image]

#### Why?

There is a bug report about it here https://developer.blender.org/T31760

it's a known error/limitation, and down to the property being intended to be used on the UI only.

For now either use `obj.scale` (with some extra manual calculation) or set the `obj.dimensions` all three at once (as shown).

Comment: This wasn't what I wanted. I wanted to change the dimension value and not scale value. Your code changes only the scale value.

Comment: Thanks, It works. I tried the second solution. But I didn't get any Invalid Context Error.  Anyway thanks. Any Idea why, my own code didn't work?

Comment: your example code did print messages into the output of Terminal / Command Prompt, but they are not caused by the setting of `obj.dimensions`.