# Cannot change x and y dimension of an object together using ob.dimensions.x and Python in Blender 3.0

Tags: python, scripting

I can not change the x dimension of an object I have created using this code:

```py
    import numpy as np
    template_object = bpy.data.objects.get('Cube')
    for y in range(3):
        for x in range(5): 
            ob = template_object.copy()
            ob.location.y = y*12
            ob.location.x = x*12
            width = np.random.randint(3,10)
            height = np.random.randint(3,10)
            print(ob.dimensions.x)
            ob.dimensions.x = height
            ob.dimensions.y = width
            bpy.context.collection.objects.link(ob)
```

Is this a known issue like [Problems with assigning dimensions through python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44307/problems-with-assigning-dimensions-through-python-script)? Or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I stumbled into the issue as well. I solved it simply by changing the scale rather than dimension.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady thanks for your comment I just found a solution I don't know if it is correct but it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the *View Layer* after assigning the value to the `dimensions`:

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C

o = C.active_object

print(o.dimensions)
o.dimensions.x = 2
C.view_layer.update()
print(o.dimensions)
o.dimensions.y = 3
C.view_layer.update()
print(o.dimensions)
o.dimensions.z = 4
C.view_layer.update()
print(o.dimensions)
```

Output for Suzanne:

```py
<Vector (2.7344, 1.7031, 1.9688)>
<Vector (2.0000, 1.7031, 1.9688)>
<Vector (2.0000, 3.0000, 1.9688)>
<Vector (2.0000, 3.0000, 4.0000)>
```

Comment: thanks actualy the first dimension that i set works well is the second that does not

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunatly this solution does not work when I try to change the y also the dimension remains unchanged even after the update. I have however upvoted it.

Comment: @GM see edit - you don't get the same results?

Comment: Now it works as expected, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can do the operation on the dimension only once, if you change first the y dimension  you will not able to change the x dimension, I have managed to change multiple dimensions at once using this code:

```
ob.dimensions.xyz = [1,2,3]
```

Where 1,2,3 are the dimension of x,y,z of course.

```
import numpy as np
template_object = bpy.data.objects.get('Cube')
for y in range(3):
    for x in range(5): 
        ob = template_object.copy()
        ob.location.y = y*12
        ob.location.x = x*12
        width = np.random.randint(3,10)
        height = np.random.randint(3,10)
        ob.dimensions.xyz = [width,height,3]
        bpy.context.collection.objects.link(ob)
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the new values just after setting them? I still get old values printed.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady yes but one I print the values they are always the same I will edit my question, but this solution actually change the size of the object correctly

Comment: You can also use `ob.dimensions = (height, width,ob.dimensions.z)` if you don't want to change the Z dimension.

Comment: @MartyFouts `[]` or `()` are optional in *multiple assignment* in Python. You could also do `ob.dimensions.xy = width, height`, but I imagine setting all 3 values is some trick solving the issue - I couldn't reproduce the issue, though, both in Blender 2.93 and Blender 3.0... My answer solves the problem of the property not updating immediately and `print` displaying an outdated value (which was edited out from the question).

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady All I was doing was observing that you can use the existing Z value in the assignment. and that `ob.dimensions` was sufficient, you don't need `.xyz`; but sure `ob.dimensions = width, height, ob.dimensions.z` is valid syntax.

Comment: @MartyFouts thanks I have to say that I prefer your solution it seems much more concise and clear

Comment: @GM your solution, not mine.  All I've done is point out a slight syntax improvement that Markus von Broady then improved.  His solution is verbose because, as he says, he was trying to explain how you could use view layer updating to refresh the information.